# PHP var and HTML form

Tags: php, forms

I am having really hard time with one online payment system. It is based Paysera.

Here is some code of the page:

```
        $request = WebToPay::buildRequest(array(
                // Čia surašyti tik keli parametrai.
                // Visų galimų parametrų su aprašymais sąrašą rasite žemiau.
                'projectid'     => xxxx,
                'sign_password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'orderid'       => 0,
                'country'       => 'LT',
                'lang'          => 'LIT',
                'amount'        => '0',
                'paytext'       => 'Parama [site_name] svetainei.',
                'accepturl'     => $self_url.'/accept.php',
                'cancelurl'     => $self_url.'/cancel.php',
                'callbackurl'   => $self_url.'/callback.php',
                'test'          => 1,
            ));
    } catch (WebToPayException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo WebToPay::PAY_URL; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($request as $key => $val): ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key ?>"
           value="<?php echo get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? $val : addslashes($val); ?>" /> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<select name="os0">
    <option name="amount" value="500">12oz/355 ml. Red party cups 50 vnt. €7.22 EUR</option>
    <option name="amount" value="700">12oz/355 ml. Red party cups 100 vnt. €11.55 EUR</option>
    <option name="amount" value="900">12oz/355 ml. Red party cups 200 vnt. €20.22 EUR</option>
    <option name="amount" value="1000">12oz/355 ml. Red party cups 500 vnt €46.23 EUR</option>
    <option name="amount" value="300">16oz/473 ml. Red party cups 50 vnt €8.08 EUR</option>
    <option name="amount" value="1200">16oz/473 ml. Blue party cups 50 vnt €8.08 EUR</option>
    <option name="amount" value="400">16oz/473 ml. Red party cups 100 vnt €13.29 EUR</option>
    <option name="amount" value="200">16oz/473 ml. Blue party cups 100 vnt €13.29 EUR</option>
    <option name="amount" value="3000">16oz/473 ml. Red party cups 200 vnt €23.11 EUR</option>
    <option name="amount" value="100">16oz/473 ml. Blue party cups 200 vnt €23.11 EUR</option>
</select>    <input type="image" border="0" name="submit" value="Mokėti" />
</form>
```

The thing is that I am kinda new to PHP. What I wanna know, that the "amount" would obtain a meaning of the value of the selected option field.

I've tried to use this:

```
'amount'        => $_POST['amount'],
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I thinked it out in some kind of speculation..

Could anyone throw me abone here? I really believe that it HAS to be a very simple way! Thanx in advance!

Comment: an `<option>` tag doesn't have a name attribute, the `<select>` tag has. Either use `$_POST['os0']` or change the select name to `name="amount"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe need do:

```
<form>
 <select name="mySelect">
  <option value="one">Firts Value</option>
  <option value="two">Second Value</option>
  <option value="three">Third Value</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

In the POST of your form you have sure a $_POST['mySelect'] with the selected value.